# Method 'onCheckboxClicked(android.view.View)' is never used

Tags: android, checkbox, fragment

Thank you guys for all the help!

Now I have updated my code and there's no error in it. But when I run the application it crashes when I try to swipe to this fragment. Is there anything missing in this code or is it something else in my app that causes this problem?

```
package hej.swipeview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class FörstängningFragment extends Fragment {


int checkOne = '0';
int checkTwo = '0';
int checkThree = '0';
ImageView bild = (ImageView)
        getView().findViewById(R.id.forstangningimage);


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forstangning, container, false);
    bild = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forstangningimage);
    bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.forstangning);
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxbak);
    CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);


    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.checkboxbak:

                    if (checked) {
                        checkOne = '1';
                        changeImage();
                    } else {
                        checkOne = '0';
                        changeImage();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            onClick(v);
        }
    });
    c2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.checkBox2:
                    if (checked) {
                        checkTwo = '1';
                        changeImage();
                    } else {
                        checkTwo = '0';
                        changeImage();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            onClick(v);
        }
    });
    c3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.checkBox3:
                    if (checked) {
                        checkThree = '1';
                        changeImage();
                    } else {
                        checkThree = '0';
                        changeImage();
                    }
                    break;
            }

            onClick(v);
        }
    });


    changeImage();
    {

        if (checkOne != '1' && checkTwo != '1' && checkThree != '1') {

            bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.forstangning);
        } else {

            if (checkOne == '1') {
                bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash2);
            } else if (checkOne == '1' && checkTwo == '1' && checkThree == '0') {
                bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.dimensioner);
            } else if (checkOne == '1' && checkTwo == '1' && checkThree == '1') {
                bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.lastmonster);
            } else if (checkOne == '1' && checkTwo == '0' && checkThree == '1') {
                bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else if (checkOne == '0' && checkTwo == '1' && checkThree == '0') {
                bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else if (checkOne == '0' && checkTwo == '1' && checkThree == '1') {
                bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else if (checkOne == '0' && checkTwo == '0' && checkThree == '1') {
                bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        }

    }
    return rootView;
}

private void changeImage() {


}

}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you are calling this function? Is the `onClick` xml attribute set on a checkbox in your layout file?

Comment: yes, I have set all the checkboxes to: android:onClick ="onCheckboxClicked"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `checkboxes` are initiated and have an `setOnClickListener(this)` inside your `Fragment`.

Inside your `onCreateView` you should have something similar to this:

```
CheckBox c = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chkName);
c.setOnClickListener(this);
```

So your `Fragment should now look similar to this:

```
public class FragmentName extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pick, container, false);

        CheckBox c = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chkName);
        c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Then make you Fragment `Override` `setOnClickListener` inside your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 // Your code here
}
```

Alternatively make sure you have set the `android:onClick` attribute inside your layout xml file:

```
 <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New CheckBox"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

As stkent pointed out from the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents)

> To define the click event handler for a button, add the android:onClick attribute to the element in your XML layout. The value for this attribute must be the name of the method you want to call in response to a click event. **The Activity hosting the layout must then implement the corresponding method.**

Comment: I have done this but it still says that: Method 'onClick(android.view.View)' is never used.

Comment: @ElinAndersson you should review stkent's answer, below. If you're sing the `onClick` attribute inside a `Fragment` view you should `override` the `onClick(View view)` method inside your parent `Activity`. To avoid this, use my first suggestion which for me is the preferred way when using `Fragments`

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents‌ (my emphasis):

> To define the click event handler for a button, add the android:onClick attribute to the  element in your XML layout. The value for this attribute must be the name of the method you want to call in response to a click event. **The Activity hosting the layout must then implement the corresponding method**.

So your `onCheckboxClicked` method needs to be implemented by the hosting Activity, not the Fragment. If this sounds dumb, it is, and you should consider *not* using the xml onClick attribute for this reason. Instead, you can set a listener programmatically in your Fragment code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are trying to set an onclick listener in a fragment. since a fragment "lives" in activity you CANNOT implicitly initiate the method in the fragment class and declare it on the xml.
To use your code simply follow the steps below - 
1. init ALL the fragment xml views before you return the infalted view

2. Set the methods BEFORE you return the inflated view and AFTER you inflated the related view, that is -

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forstangning, container, false);
    bild = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.forstangningimage);
    bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.forstangning);
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxbak);
    CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick(v);//THIS IS THE METHOD YOU WROTE ON THE ATTACHED CODE!!
        }
    });
    c2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick(v);//THIS IS THE METHOD YOU WROTE ON THE ATTACHED CODE!!
        }
    });
    c3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick(v);//THIS IS THE METHOD YOU WROTE ON THE ATTACHED CODE!!
        }
    });

    return rootView;

}
```

PS - 
Change the name you gave to the onClick method you created to something else, otherwise you will have a collision in the naming of the overrided method in the listener and the method you have created.